# Compare two lists row by row and return if same values

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Hi I have two lists.

```
predicted = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0]
actualnum = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0]
```

I would like to know how to compare these two lists by each number and get the number on how many match.

Basically:

```
if predicted[0] matches actualnum[0] then 1
if predicted[0] matches actualnum[1] then 0
```

so i would have:

```
predicted[0] not equal to actualnum[0] = 0
predicted[1] equal to actualnum[1] = 1
predicted[2] not equal to actualnum[2] = 1
etc.
```

In the end I would have 4 out of 6 matches.

How can I make the for loop for this. I have looked at examples but the only say set(a)&set(b) - however this only shows how many similar numbers are in the sets. However I really just need to compare the values in the same index [0] only with [0] and [1] only with [1].

Comment: use recursion. Here is an example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53435823/python-3-applying-recursion-to-compare-lists

Comment: for i in range(len(predicted) ):
    If predicted[I] == actualnum[I]:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `ith` value of both lists many different ways. Here are some options:

```
for i in range(len(predicted)):
    p = predicted[i]
    a = actualnum[i]
```

```
for i, p in enumerate(predicted):
    a = actualnum[i]
```

```
for p, a in zip(predicted, actualnum):
```

In the body of the loop, simply compare `p` and `a` and print whatever you like if they're equal or not.

If you just want to know how many values match, you can do something like:

```
matches = sum(1 for p, a in zip(predicted, actualnum) if p == a)
```